# Throwable onError component of subscription not compiling as expected

Tags: java, rx-android, throwable, rxandroidble

Trying to set up monitoring of the RxAndroidBle connection status with an Observable. The code below compiles (I'm unable to test it yet), but I don't fully understand why. The second parameter of the `subscribe` call is supposed to be `Action1<java.lang.Throwable> onError`. Have I implemented this correctly? Why can't I just write

```
throwable -> throw throwable
```

When I try, the second "throwable" is flagged "cannot resolve symbol 'throwable'", and between the "->" and "throw" it says it's expecting either a right paren, left brace, or semicolon.

```
// set up monitoring of connection state with a subscription
boolean setConnectionStateNotification() {
    asBleDevice.observeConnectionStateChanges()
        .subscribe(
            connectionState -> asBleConnectionState = connectionState,
            throwable -> new RuntimeException( "Problem with subscription to Connection State Changes: "
                            + throwable.getMessage() )
            );
    return true;
}
```

TBH I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the concept of an `Action1<Throwable>`; can someone explain it, please?

UPDATE: I think I may have figured it out. Like so:

```
 boolean setConnectionStateNotification() {
    asBleDevice.observeConnectionStateChanges() // returns Observable<RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState>
        .subscribe(
            connectionState -> asBleConnectionState = connectionState,
            throwable -> { throw new RuntimeException(
                "Problem with subscription to Connection State Changes: "
                    + throwable.getMessage(), throwable );
            },
            ( ) -> RxBleLog.d( "Connection State Observable has completed", null ) // onCompleted() with no arguments
            ); // subscribe
    return true;
}
```

(I also added the third optional handler, for the onCompleted() call.)

Comment: Hello. Could you describe what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be right:

```
boolean setConnectionStateNotification() {
    asBleDevice.observeConnectionStateChanges() // returns Observable<RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState>
        .subscribe(
            connectionState -> asBleConnectionState = connectionState, // save value
            throwable -> { throw new RuntimeException(
                "Problem with subscription to Connection State Changes: "
                    + throwable.getMessage(), throwable );
            },
            ( ) -> RxBleLog.d( "Connection State Observable has completed", null ) // onCompleted() with no arguments
        ); // subscribe
    return true;
}
```